# C# Sort Script/Picking the last Int from a foreach

Tags: c#

i need some help with my sort script. I wanna sort some files.
This is how the Name is constructed: Name#Page#Version
I can pick the Name/category and the page but i dont know how to pick the last version :/
Here you can see an example.
[image]

```
foreach(string files in Directory.GetFiles(path).OrderBy(fi => fi.Length))
        {
            try
            {
                filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files);


                index = filename.LastIndexOf("#");
                index2 = filename.LastIndexOf("#",index-1);

                strversion = filename.Substring(index+1);
                strpage = filename.Substring(index2+1);
                strpage = strpage.Substring(0, strpage.LastIndexOf("#"));                    

                page = Int32.Parse(strpage);
                version = Int32.Parse(strversion);
                Console.WriteLine("Page: "+page);
                Console.WriteLine("Version: "+version);

                if (filename.Contains("SMA"))
                {

                    if (page == 1)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(filename);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you should best split the filename by # using `filename.Split('#')` and then parse the parts.

Comment: yea thx for the tipp :) but i will have the same problem that i cant pick the last version :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your requirement, you want to

1. filter out every file not containing "SMA"
2. then order by page
3. then by version

You can achieve this quite declaratively using LINQ:

```
var orderedFileNames =
fileNames
    .Where(fn=>fn.Contains("SMA")
    // parse name
    .Select(fn => fn.Split('#')) 
    // pull parts into anonymous type
    .Select(fn => new { 
        Name = fn[0], Page = int.Parse(fn[1]), Version = int.Parse(fn[2])
    })
    .OrderBy(fn=>fn.Name)
    .ThenBy(fn=>fn.Page)
    .ThenBy(fn=>fn.Version);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're over complicating things, you can split the string by `#` and get what you want from the array given:

```
var fileName = "SMA#1#2";
var parts = fileName.Split('#');
var name = parts[0];
var page = parts[1];
var version = parts[2];
```

**EDIT**

As for getting the last `version` for each `page`, you're probably better off creating some sort of class for your file and then grouping by page, and then sorting by version, and then selecting the first one:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var fileNames = new[] { "SMA#1#1", "SMA#1#2", "SMA#1#3", "SMA#2#1", "SMA#2#3" };
        var files = (from fileName in fileNames select fileName.Split('#') into parts let name = parts[0] let page = Int32.Parse(parts[1]) let version = Int32.Parse(parts[2]) select new MyFile(name, page, version)).ToList();
        var grouped = files.GroupBy(x => x.Page).ToList();
        foreach (var group in grouped)
        {
            var ordered = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version);
            Console.WriteLine($"Page {group.Key} highest version: {ordered.First().Version}");
        }
    }
}

public class MyFile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }

    public MyFile(string name, int page, int version)
    {
        Name = name;
        Page = page;
        Version = version;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer for the main part of your question, from how I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int lastIndex = filename.LastIndexOf("#");
string version = fileName.SubString(lastIndex, fileName.Length - lastIndex);
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No i got the version number but i want only the last one of each page

Comment: Create something like that:

    public class OrderIt 
    { 
    public string FileName {get; set;}
    public int Version {get; set;}
    }

Now you put all files into a List<OrderIt>

    list.Where(n => n.FileName==yourFileName).OrderByDescending(n 
     => n.Version).FirstOrDefault()